# Getting answer from a dynamic page with multiple inputs field

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm new to react native development. Im creating a dynamic page with json data (multiple components types like input ,radio props,dropdown,text area,image,combolist).

I have rendered the dynamic screen with multiple components in react native from json. But the problem i'm facing now is - how to fetch the component values in save/submit action as they are dynamically generated fields. there is  unique key 'id' will be available for each component.

```
{  
   "type":"textfield",
   "question":"some questions?",
   "id":1
},
{  
   "type":"radiobutton",
   "question":"some questions?",
   "id":2
},
{  
   "type":"combolist",
   "question":"some questions?",
   "id":3
}
```

I need the value entered in the above 3 components on save/submit action. 
Note: The size of the fields in a page varies from 100-300 fields.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to understand how to forms work in React and React Native. There is something called as onChange function associated with React and React Native forms.

Please check out the link mentioned below on for capturing information submitted via the form
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/handling-text-input